# NW.js (node-webkit) and Vue.js issue with require systeminformation module

Tags: vue.js, node-webkit, system-information

I have a project that uses NW.js in conjunction with Vue.js. The problem is that I can't include [systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) module to the Vue.js because according to the [documentation](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation#core-concept) (see the core concept section) this lib doesn't work from inside the [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) but only on a server-side.
How to include this lib in nw.js to make it available globally so I can use it from inside the vue code?

I've been using a solution that seemed to work but recently I figured out that it isn't. What I've been doing - I included script right in the **./public/index.html** and it works on dev but not on the build. When I build the app and move it to another place it just can't find the path to the **systeminformation** package.

```html
<!-- inside index.html -->

<script>
  const si = require("systeminformation");
</script>
```

Any idea how to overcome this? Would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way you are using Vue. If you are doing a simple "CDN" style then look at this example:

- https://gitlab.com/TheJaredWilcurt/battery-app-workshop/-/blob/finished-app/scripts/main.js

The README in that repo will give step-by-step instructions.

If you are using the **Vue-CLI** style, then this should work:

- https://github.com/nwutils/nw-vue-cli-example/blob/master/src/components/FsExample.vue#L47

That repo is a complete boilerplate for Vue-CLI + NW.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would double vote if I could. This is really the right direction. I use a Vue-CLI style. Deleted require from the index.html and added require to my mixin (inside methods as a const) like in the boilerplate example and all works, however only on dev. When I build a project and move the app into the Applications folder on my mac it shows the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'systeminformation' ....... chunk-vendors.8f50b667.js:7`. What could it be?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my assumption is whatever you are using to "build" is not doing an `npm install` in the build output, or perhaps your don't have `systeminformation` in your dependencies in the `package.json` (`devDependencies` are usually stripped from prod builds). Use the `nw-vue-cli-example` boilerplate for an easier time.

Comment: You were right! The issue is that somehow my dependency is not packaging to the 'chunk-vendors'. If I manually adding node_modules with the package that is missing, the app begins to work. Now I need to figure out why this happens. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "chunk vendors" sounds like a webpack thing. It cannot bundle native modules, you need to handle that yourself. Again, if you use the boilerplate I linked, it will handle builds for you.

Comment: Yes, I examined the boilerplate code yesterday, there are a lot of interesting things in there, thanks for the link.